# jQuery UI slider labels - follow handles on resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, position

I'm using labels to display handle values with jQuery UI slider.

How can I maintain the position of these values on resize?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/vc8tumg9/3/

```
$(label).html(hours + ':' + minutes).position({
my: 'top center',
at: 'bottom center',
of: ui.handle,
offset: "0, 30"
});
```

For extra credit... can you tell me why my initial values aren't displaying in the correct position (as on slide)?

For double extra credit... can you tell me how to bind slide to the label in addition to the handle?

Comment: I don't believe that this will work `$('.pct-slider eq(0)')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a label using css... the only major issue is getting an initial value added as the `create` event does not provide the `ui` variable ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/vc8tumg9/5/)):

CSS

```
/* Add tooltips to slider handles */
 .ui-slider-handle:after {
    content : attr(data-value);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: -24px;
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: #ddd 1px solid;
    color: #333;
    font: .7em/1em Arial, Sans-Serif;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-slider-handle:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 8px solid #eee;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    top: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Script

```
var initialValues = [180, 330, 1080, 1320],
    updateValue = function (ui) {
    var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
    var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

    if (hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
    if (minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;
    if (minutes == 0) minutes = '00';
    if (hours >= 12) {
        if (hours == 12) {
            hours = hours;
            minutes = minutes + " PM";
        } else {
            hours = hours - 12;
            minutes = minutes + " PM";
        }
    } else {
        hours = hours;
        minutes = minutes + " AM";
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
        minutes = minutes;
    }
    $(ui.handle).attr('data-value', hours + ':' + minutes);
};

$(".pct-slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    range: false,
    values: initialValues,
    create: function (event, ui) {
        $.each( initialValues, function(i, v){
            updateValue({
                value: v,
                handle: $('.ui-slider-handle').eq(i) 
            });
        });
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        updateValue(ui);
    }
});
```

Comment: Here is another method I've found (http://codepen.io/ignaty/pen/EruAe).. I think it's pretty cool because the labels merge together when in close proximity.

Comment: This is fantastic... best way to initially populate the labels with the handle values on load?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. On my production site I am still having difficulty getting the values to pre-populate the labels... BUT... I think it's because I have the slider inside a jQuery Tabs div which has caused problems for me in the past. I'll have to do some research.